# Data type of phone number, Parse, Twilio, SMS

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, twilio

What should be the data type of the phone Number used to sent SMS via twilio and Parse? In other words, what data type should the variable number be in the following code:

```
 // Create the Cloud Function
    Parse.Cloud.define("sendSMSVerification", function(request, response) {
     // Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS
      twilio.sendSMS({
        From: "########",
        To: request.params.number,
        Body: "test" //request.params.message//SMS Verification: 1234 or     whatever the specific number is...
      }, {
    success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
    error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went    wrong"); }
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems the answer is a string.  Two answers are given to that effect.  It helps others use this site when the questioner marks correct the answer that he/she found to be correct.

Comment: but theyre both right...

Comment: I'd up-vote both and pick the better in your opinion

Answer (score 2):

Phone numbers should be always stored and declared as strings or varchars, the main "technical" reason for this is that phone numbers are not always just numbers, there are many instances where other characters as '*', '+', "ext." may be part of a phone number and it may cause a type issue in the long run.

Now, integers, floats, etc. exist as a type in part to facilitate operations among numbers, is not the same "2" + "3" as 2 + 3, so since phone numbers will never operate as numbers, it makes only sense to handle them always as strings.

Answer (score 0):

As per Twilio Demo App Code, Number should be in sent as String.

`NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString`*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty,identifier);

```
[self sendSMSToNumber:phoneNumber];

- (void)sendSMSToNumber:(NSString *)number {
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:number forKey:@"number"];
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"inviteWithTwilio" withParameters:params block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
        NSString *message = @"";
        if (!error) {
            message = @"Your SMS invitation has been sent!";
        } else {
            message = @"Uh oh, something went wrong :(";
        }

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invite Sent!"
                                    message:message
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```